# How to get keyboard button state avoiding key release messages

Tags: c++, winapi

I have program in which i have registered hotkeys using [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) function, and in action of that hotkey i need to release the modifiers so i send [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) with `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` flag for each modifier L/R of Ctrl, Shift, Alt and Win. And after that if i press only hotkey's key(while still holding modifiers **physically**) it won't work, because modifiers were up.

So is there way to determine whichever key is hold physically(keyboard button) regardless of key up messages? So i can press them again after hotkey action.

For now i have function that checks the modifiers before hotkey action and press them again after action, but what if i already released the modifiers physically on keyboard(e.g. before hotkey's action end), then the modifiers will stuck.

Example code(mingw):

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "tchar.h"

int _tmain() {
    if (RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_ALT, 0x42))  //0x42 is 'b'
        _tprintf(_T("Hotkey 'ALT+b' registered\n"));

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
            if (msg.wParam == 1) {
                int alt;
                alt = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LMENU) && 0x8000;
                if (alt == 1) { // If alt were down.
                    _tprintf("Releasing alt.\n");
                    keybd_event(VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                }
                //hotkey_action();
                // if you release the alt before Sleep ends it will stuck, and to send it up you'll need to press left AND right Alt keys.
                Sleep(600); // Consider this as hotkey_action();
                _tprintf(_T("Hotkey %d received, alt: %d\n"), msg.wParam, alt);
                // alt = GetPhysicalKeyState(VK_LMENU); or something like that
                if (alt == 1) { // Press again
                    _tprintf("Pressing again alt.\n");
                    keybd_event(VK_LMENU,0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Try pressing `Alt+b` and release Alt before `Sleep(600)` ends, alt will stuck.

In `hotkey_action()` I use multiple `SendInput` calls which simulate keyboard presses, thats why i need to release modifiers before it.

So the main question is: "How can i get modifiers **physical**(button on keyboard) state after i released them by windows message?"

Comment: What are you *really* trying to accomplish? Sounds like you are asking about your solution rather than your goal. This is known as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @IInspectable I said it already in title and the end of post: `How to get keyboard button state avoiding key release messages` and `How can i get modifiers physical(button on keyboard) state after i released them by windows message?` e.g. something like `GetPhysicalKeyState()` function.